# HttpUrlConnection looking up DNS every time cause delay some time

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I use HttpUrlConnection for http requesting in my app. Notice that it look up the dns in every request via Wireshark. The dns may delay some time, so the http request delays too. I don't think it need to look up the DNS every time, since the ip address of the serve would change rarely. I want to know how to avoid looking up the DNS every time.

Here is part of my code:

```
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        String postContent = URLEncoder.encode(kJSonKey, charset) + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(jsonStr, charset);
        URL url = new URL(kWebServiceUrl);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Charset", charset);
        urlConnection.connect();
        dos = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        dos.write(postContent.getBytes());
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
```

Comment: So fix your DNS. It should be instaneous. If it isn't it is slowing down everything in the network, not just `HttpURLConnection.`

Comment: @EJP he cant fix it for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it's the router problem.